# C code to a HEX file

Tags: c, linux, windows, embedded, file-conversion

I'm using Linux in my work lab to convert `.c` code to `.elf/.hex` in order to load it to a Teensy++ 2.0. How could I do this using Windows at home? Is there a **C to HEX converter?**

This is the terminal commands I'm using in Linux:

`avr-gcc -mmcu=at90usb1286 –o <output.elf> <input.c> usb_serial.c`

`avr-objcopy –O ihex <output.elf> <output.hex>`

Comment: That's called a _compiler_

Comment: Can't you install Linux on your home computer?

Comment: IIRC, GCC linker has options for output files; Intel hex, Motorola S-records.

Comment: You've got the process wrong - the compiler generates the .elf file, objcopy converts the .elf object code to .hex.  Converting a .c file to .hex would not result in a valid load image because it would just be a hex representation of the source code text and not the compiled binary machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if you are already used to avr-gcc on Linux and want to accomplish the same task on windows, then what you want is a build of avr-gcc for your windows box.

An easy way to obtain one is to install the Arduino IDE, which brings along its own copy.  You can simply ignore the IDE and arduino libraries, and use the installed avr-gcc directly just as you do now.

Another source of a windows port is winavr

Answer (score 1):

avr-gcc is available for Windows too, so you can do it in exactly the same way on Windows.  You need [WInAVR](http://www.webring.org/l/rd?ring=avr;id=59;url=http://winavr.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:http://www.engineersgarage.com/forums/8051/how-convert-c-code-hex-code-using-keil-compiler